# After onActivityResult event State Is Gone (Droid Phones)

Tags: android

I have a problem that's only affecting Droid phones.  I end up not being able to access global variables after an onActivityResult event.

While looking into this I came across:
[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

I follow those directions, but still the value is NULL.

On my HTC Hero everything I've tried works.  On Droid phones everything is NULL or an empty string.

What I need is the URL from the webview.  In the onPageFinished I've been putting the URL into a global variable.  The app has the correct URL in that method because that's when I pop open the imagepicker.  After that is when the global variable value is gone.  I also can't read the webview (I can on my Hero, can't on Droid's) after hitting the onActivityResult event.  GetUrl() returns NULL for them, works fine for me.  Everything also works fine in the simulator.  I've 1.5, 2.1, and 2.2 in the simulator.

How else can I store the info I need to retrieve?